# how do I enforce referential integrity between a many to many table and its parent tables

Tags: sql-server-express

I have 4 tables.

- Table 1 stores data for Airlines
- Table 2 stores data for Destinations
- Table 3 stores unique Routes(each route is a unique combination of airline and destination).
- Table 4 records the prices of all flights on the routes in table 3. This is a **many to many** table as there are many flights by each airline to many destinations.

Table 1 = `Airlines`

```
    Airline_ICAO_Code varchar(3) Not NULL Primary key,
    Airline varchar(22) NULL
```

Table 2 = `Destinations`

```
    Airport_ICAO_Code varchar(4) Not NULL Primary key,
    Destination varchar(30) NULL
```

Table 3 = `Airlines2Destinations`

```
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Airport_ICAO_Code varchar(4) Not NULL Foreign Key References Destinations(Airport_ICAO_Code),
Destination varchar(30) NULL,
    Airline_ICAO_Code varchar(3) Not NULL Foreign Key References Airlines(Airline_ICAO_Code),
    Airline varchar(22) NULL
```

Table 4 = `Airlines2DestinationsPrices`

```
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Airport_ICAO_Code varchar(4) Not NULL Foreign Key References Destinations(Airport_ICAO_Code),
    Destination varchar(30) NULL,
    Airline varchar(22) NULL,
    Airline_ICAO_Code varchar(3) Not NULL Foreign Key References Airlines(Airline_ICAO_Code),
    Departure smalldatetime,
    Price smallmoney
```

My problem is how do I enforce referential integrity between tables 3 and 4. This is necessary as the routes entered in table 4 must be present in table 3. I need advice as to what way to set up the Primary keys on Table 3 and Table 4 that will enable me to do this.

I am considering using a composite key on table 3 like this:

```
Primary Key(Airport_ICAO_Code,Airline_ICAO_Code)
```

or concatenating the `Airport_ICAO_Code` and `Airport_ICAO_Code` columns into a new column and dropping the ID columns.

If I use the `Identity` column as the primary key for both tables there is no guarantee that the ID for a route in Table 4 will match the ID for a route in Table 3.

Because of all these options I'm unsure of the best way forward. If someone could take the time to help out on this it would really be appreciated.

Thanks for any help offered

Edit:
After receiving advice from Marc in the post below I set up Table 4 as follows. However there is no primary key on this table. Would the ID column be better for the Primary key or could I use a Composite Key like this `Primary Key (Airlines2DestinationsID,Departure).`

```
Table 4 = Airlines2DestinationsPrices

ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
Airlines2DestinationsID INT NOT NULL
    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Airlines2Destiations(ID),
Departure smalldatetime,
Price smallmoney
```

Comment: what database? there is no mention of a primary key or any unique constraints in the table definitions. presumably the id column on table 3 marked identity is uniqie so creating a destinations_id column or whatever you want to call it on your airline 2 destinations and referencing that would save a lot of hassle.

Comment: For things like codes that are **fixed length** (always 3 characters for the airline code, 4 characters for the airport code), I'd recommend using the `char(3)` and `char(4)` datatypes. Those carry no overhead (other than the `varchar` types)

Comment: Apologies. Ive put in the primary keys for Table 1 and 2 now. I do not have primary keys set yet for Tables 3 and 4. im using sql server express 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if any one entry in table 4 always belongs to a single entry in table 3, I would just store the `Airlines2Destiations.ID` as a foreign key into table 4.

That way, each entry of table 4 is always clearly and uniquely connected to a single entry in table 3. Also: drop all the **redudancy** from table 4 - you only need the reference to table 3 - you don't need to repeat airline or airport codes and names.

Table 3 = Airlines2Destinations

```
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
Airport_ICAO_Code CHAR(4) NOT NULL 
     Foreign Key References Destinations(Airport_ICAO_Code),
Destination VARCHAR(30) NULL,
Airline_ICAO_Code CHAR(3) NOT NULL 
     Foreign Key References Airlines(Airline_ICAO_Code),
Airline VARCHAR(22) NULL
```

Table 4 = Airlines2DestinationsPrices

```
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
Airlines2DestinationsID INT NOT NULL
    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Airlines2Destiations(ID),
Departure smalldatetime,
Price smallmoney
```

Comment: Thanks very much Marc, thats very helpful. Regarding dropping the redundant data - i left the Airline and Destination Columns in Table 4 to make it easier to edit if i needed to. Its hard to see what needs to be edited when looking at the airline codes. Do you see my point or do you still think its better to get rid of them

Comment: Thanks very much Marc, thats very helpful. Regarding dropping the redundant data - i left the Airline and Destination Columns in Table 4 to make it easier to edit if i needed to. Its hard to see what needs to be edited when looking at the airline codes. I will drop the code columns but it will be difficult to edit prices by just having the Airlines2Destinations ID number to reference. Do you see my point or do you still think its better to get rid of them

Comment: @frustrationmultiplied: the whole point of **database normalization** is to **avoid redundancies** - what happens if you edit something in table 4, and don't update it elsewhere? You'll have **inconsistent** data - not something you want in a RDBMS !!

Comment: I see your point but how would you go about editing table 4 assuming its set up the way you recommended above. for example assume you have to input a price for Delta Airlines to New York and you didnt know the ID of the route and assuming there are many flights already in the table how would you find the correct record without having to refer back to table 3 all the time

Comment: You have to have a decent GUI on top of this database that will pull the relevant bits and pieces from the other tables, and present them in a single page. Have a single GUI to edit everything, but **store** it in separate, linked tables.

Comment: Ok. Im studying for the MCSA atm but havent covered GUI yet. In the meantime if i want to input prices is referring back to table 3 the only way of editing them for now.

Comment: I forgot to ask you Marc, should I also set the ID column in table 4 as a Primary key?

Comment: @frustrationmultiplied: yes, absolutely